# Browser video interruptions

Tags: video, browser

When I play videos either on chrome or firefox it interrupts playback for a split second every few minutes.

PC was just installed with xubuntu. Regarding to lsb_release -a version is as follows: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Arch is playing video without problems btw.

What can I do? Its driving me mad.

Comment: Graphics card?...

Comment: runs on arch linux since over a year